# How can I dynamic pass value to my modal with button?

Tags: php, modal-dialog

```
<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12" class="text-center bg-primary text-white" style="font-size:20px;">List all people</td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        if($result->num_rows>0){
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                $people=new People;
                $people->id=$row['id'];
                $people->firstname=$row['firstname'];
                $people->lastname=$row['lastname'];
                $people->email=$row['email'];
                $people->registerdate=$row['reg_date'];
                echo "<tr>
                <td style='width:60px;' name='id'>$people->id<td>
                <td>$people->firstname<td>
                <td>$people->lastname<td>
                <td>$people->email<td>
                <td>$people->registerdate<td>
                <td><button class='btn btn-danger w-100' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal'>Action</button><td>
                <tr>";
                require('modal.php');
            }
        }
        ?>
        <div class="modal fade" id="mymodal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo "User : $people->firstname $people->lastname" ?></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <label for="">User ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $people->id ?>">
                        <label for="">First name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $people->firstname ?>">
                        <label for="">Last name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $people->lastname ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        modal footer
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </table>
```

Comment: What is in "modal.php"

Comment: What's your question about this code? What have you tried to resolve your question?

Comment: Please next time provide a small description of the problem when you ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using jQuery for this purpose.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="12" class="text-center bg-primary text-white" style="font-size:20px;">List all people</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    if($result->num_rows>0)
    {
        $serial_no = 0;
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $serial_no++;
            $people=new People;
            $people->id=$row['id'];
            $people->firstname=$row['firstname'];
            $people->lastname=$row['lastname'];
            $people->email=$row['email'];
            $people->registerdate=$row['reg_date'];
            echo "<tr>
            <td style='width:60px;' name='id'>$people->id<td>
            <td>$people->firstname<td>
            <td>$people->lastname<td>
            <td>$people->email<td>
            <td>$people->registerdate<td>";
            ?>
            <td>
                <button class='btn btn-danger w-100' data-toggle='modal' onclick="open_modal('<?php echo $people->id; ?>', '<?php echo $people->firstname; ?>', '<?php echo $people->lastname; ?>');" data-target='#mymodal'>Action</button>
            <td>
            <tr>
            <?php
            require('modal.php');
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>
<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo "User : $people->firstname $people->lastname" ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label for="">User ID</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="people_id">
                <label for="">First name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="people_firstname">
                <label for="">Last name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="people_lastname">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                modal footer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function open_modal(id, first_name, last_name)
{
    $("#people_id").val (id);
    $("#people_firstname").val (first_name);
    $("#people_lastname").val (last_name);
    $("#mymodal").modal("show");
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is exactly 0 jquery in here, or am i being stupid?

Comment: all the coding within open_modal function is in jQuery.

Comment: THere's only php in the open_modal function?

Comment: yes. the values are changing using jquery